# Composer does not find dependencies of vcs repository

Tags: composer-php

i've got a strange problem ...

project-a is my main project.
project-b is my library, checked in to subversion

composer.json of project-b

```
{
"name": "fragger/baseclasses",
"version" : "0.0.1-dev",
"description": "Baseclasses and Interfaces",
"require": {
    "silex/silex": "1.0.x-dev",
    "3rd-party/smarty": "3.*",
    "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "4.2-dev"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "baseclasses": "src/" }
}
}
```

and composer.json of project-b

```
{
"repositories" : [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url" : "svn+ssh://....."
    }
],
"require": {
    "fragger/baseclasses": ">=0.0.1-dev"
}
}
```

output of install command

```
php composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies                               
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for fragger/baseclasses >=0.0.1-dev -> satisfiable by     fragger/baseclasses dev-trunk.
    - fragger/baseclasses dev-trunk requires silex/silex 1.0.x-dev -> no matching package     found.
```

But a composer install in project a alone, works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find detailed information about the packages on [packgist](https://packagist.org/), for example for [`Silex`](https://packagist.org/packages/silex/silex), but it seems, that all of your dependencies have invalid version strings.

Instead of `"silex/silex": "1.0.x-dev"` it must be named `"silex/silex": "1.0.*@dev"`. There is no branch for `1.0.x` and the correct version string for a branch would be `dev-branchname` anyway ;)